# In ggplot, how can I parameterize several curves/function using values from a data.frame and plot them in different facets?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, facet, curve

It's great that I can plot a custom curve in ggplot by specifying arguments to stat_function. However, if I have a whole set of parameters, and I want to compare how the resulting curves compare to each other, the process seems a bit more complicated. I suppose I could manually make a dataframe for each parameter set, but perhaps there is a more elegant way to do this in ggplot.

```
library(ggplot2)

# Create a plot with x axis from -5 to 5
base <- ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-5, 5)), aes(x))
base

# Create a custom named function with an additional argument
f <- function(.x, a) a*exp(-abs(.x))

# We can specify values for the argument in stat_function
base + stat_function(fun = f, args=list(a=1))

# Create a data.frame with a range of possible parameter values
df <- data.frame(par=1:4, factor=c("a", "b", "c", "d"))

# How can I get four facets - one for each factor/parameter value, without having to specify df$ each time? 
# Below is sort of what I am aiming for but it produces an error.
base + stat_function(fun = f, args=list(a=df$par)) + facet_wrap(df$factor)
```